# How to use Yii2 user Identity in Codeception unit test case?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, phpunit, codeception

I am new to unit testing. Trying to create some test cases in my Yii2 project using codeception plugin. From last 1 week i am learning it.

Now i know how to use Fixtures, Mocks and Stubs in Unit testing.

I just want to ask that can we use Yii2 user identity class in unit testing in some cases. for example there may be case when we have to check some condition for logged in user. in that case how to use user session or user identity in unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of unit testing is to test a single, specific part of your code, like a function or method. If you test a function or method, which has dependencies, like getting an user id or an database record, the intention of unit testing is to mock or stub every dependencies of your method.

The alternative way is to rebuild/recreate the bootstrapped application in your test. That means in your case: calling the right methods to create the user-object, for example by calling the login-methods.

If you like to test a whole part of your application, than -maybe- functional test are the right test-type for your case. Here you start with a full bootstrapped application, where you can first login the user (be calling the user page) and than executing your testcase.

But:
If you only need any login in the test, then you can also define a dummy user class for the test. This means:

1. in `config/test.php` add something like that for using the dummy user model:

   ```php
   'user' => [
               'identityClass' => 'app\tests\models\DummyUser',
               'loginUrl' => ['site/login'],
               'enableAutoLogin' => true,
               'enableSession' => true,
             ],
   ```
2. create an dummy user model in `app\tests\models\DummyUser`, that implements all the methods needed by `IdentityIngterface`, like that:

   ```php
   namespace app\tests\models;

   use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
   use app\models\User;


   class DummyUser extends User implements IdentityInterface
   {
      public $id = "Foo";

       public static function findIdentity($id)
       {   
           // always return the same dummy user
           return new static ([
               'id' => 'dummyUser',
               'email' => 'dummyUser@domain',
               'name' => 'Dummy User'

           ]);
       }

       public static function findGuestIdentity()
       {
            return new static ([
               'id' => 'guest',
               'email' => '',
               'name' => 'Guest User'

           ]);
       }

       public static function findGast()
       {
           return new static ([
               'id' => 'guest'
           ]);
       }
       /**
        * This method is needed to satisfy the interface.
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
       {
           return true;
       }

       /**
        * This method is needed to satisfy the interface.
        * 
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function getId()
       {
           return true;
       }

       /**
        * This method is needed to satisfy the interface.
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function getAuthKey()
       {
           return "bar";
       }

       /**
        * This method is needed to satisfy the interface.
        * {@inheritdoc}
        */
       public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

   3. In your unit test use `Yii` and your dummy user model `use app\test\models\DummyUser` and run an fake login in before block of your test-class:

   ```php
   protected function _before()
   {
       $dummyLogin = DummyUser::findIdentity('dummyUser');
       Yii::$app->user->login($dummyLogin);
   }
   ```

Now, Yii2 user identity is available in yii2 codeception unit test. Now you have an (fake) login for unit test in Yii2.